# Format a date in label regardless of culture

Tags: c#, datetime, localization, format, culture

In my ascx page i have :

```
    <tr>
        <td class="lbl">Geboortedatum</td>
        <td class="lbl">:</td>
        <td class="data">
            <asp:Label ID="tbBirthDate"  CssClass="details" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

This Birtdate is filled from the cs file :

```
        var cust = (from c in db.tbCustomers
                    join s in db.tbStreets on new { c.StreetId, c.PostCode } equals new { s.StreetId, s.PostCode }
                    join p in db.tbPostalAreas on s.PostCode equals p.PostCode
                    where c.Id == customerId
                    select new
                    {
                        FirstNames = c.FirstNames,
                        MiddleName = c.MiddleName,
                        LastName = c.LastName,
                        BirthDate = string.Format("{0:dd-mm-yyyy}", c.BirthDate.Value.ToShortDateString()),
                        StreetName = s.Street,
                        HouseNumber = c.HouseNumber,
                        PostCode = c.PostCode,
                        PostCodeLetters = c.StreetId,
                        City = p.City,
                        Email = c.Email,
                        Mobile = c.PhoneMobile,
                        PickUpAddress = c.PickupAddress

                    }).SingleOrDefault();

        if (cust != null)
        {
            tbFirstName.Text = cust.FirstNames;
            tbLastName.Text = (cust.MiddleName != null) ? cust.MiddleName + " " + cust.LastName : cust.LastName;
            tbBirthDate.Text = cust.BirthDate;
            tbStreetName.Text = cust.StreetName + " " + cust.HouseNumber;
            tbPostCode.Text = cust.PostCode + " " + cust.PostCodeLetters;
            tbCity.Text = cust.City;
            tbEmail.Text = cust.Email;
            tbMobile.Text = cust.Mobile;
            tbPickupAddress.Text = cust.PickUpAddress;
        }
```

Now when running locally i get a date like 26-10-2011, but when placed on my server i get 10/26/2011
How can i force the date to be shown as 26-10-2011 ?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to format the date twice:

```
string.Format("{0:dd-mm-yyyy}", c.BirthDate.Value.ToShortDateString())
```

Remove the call to `ToShortDateString`

```
string.Format("{0:dd-mm-yyyy}", c.BirthDate.Value)
```

#### Update

Or better yet:

```
c.BirthDate.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

To make really certain that the culture isn't impacting things, you could specify the culture explicitly:

```
c.BirthDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", 
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't change anything

Comment: Then there must be something else going on here, because "dd-mm-yyyy" would produce *minutes* on "mm". If you're seeing no change in behavior, it's likely that something's not getting applied correctly. Try extracting out this logic into a separate method and putting a breakpoint in the method to see if it's even being run.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you replace:

```
BirthDate = string.Format("{0:dd-mm-yyyy}", c.BirthDate.Value.ToShortDateString()),
```

with:

```
BirthDate = string.Format("{0:dd-mm-yyyy}", c.BirthDate.Value).
```

it should work

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
string.Format("{0:dd-mm-yyyy}", c.BirthDate.Value.ToShortDateString())
```

You're trying to format the date as a string with a specific format, but you have already transformed the date into a string with `ToShortDateString` (using the current culture). The format you specified in `string.Format` doesn't make sense for a string...

Instead you should format the date like this:

```
c.BirthDate.ToString("dd-MM-YYYY");
```

By the way, note the "MM" part instead of "mm": mm is for minutes, which proves the format you specified wasn't taken into account in your current code

Answer (score 0):

Replace `BirthDate = string.Format("{0:dd-mm-yyyy}", c.BirthDate.Value.ToShortDateString())` with `BirthDate = string.Format("{0:dd-mm-yyyy}", c.BirthDate.Value)`.

The first form first gets the date, then the local-form of the short date string, then does a format on it that does nothing. The second gets the date and then does a format on it that puts it into dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make this line

> ```
>  tbBirthDate.Text = cust.BirthDate;
> ```

into `tbBirthDate.Text = cust.BirthDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`;

This wont take into account any cultureinfo ofcourse!